# how to display profile pic for facebook using sharekit, iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I need to publish users profile pic that is available in facebook in my iphone app.
Can you guys please suggest how to make this done using sharekit.

Thanks,
Chaitanya.,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ShareKit` is made for that purpose. The idea is to enable sharing on multiple platforms. For getting the profile pic, you will need to use Facebook's official [iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

The relevant graph API would be:
`https://graph.facebook.com/username/picture`

Answer (score 0):

There is no graph API for updating the profile picture. You can only retrieve it. However, it is possible to update it, check out [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/profilepic/id431653745?mt=8).

The general approach would be to do a straight up POST to Facebook with the image and the crop dimensions for the final profile picture. However, since that isn't an API-based approach - your code will be brittle.

Sharekit is not the way to go for Facebook profile pictures, but you CAN update a Twitter profile picture with it.